# Finding the encoding of a text file containing weird characters

Tags: vim, encoding, character-encoding, decoding

I recently received a file, of Turkish origin, where the file has some English words which I can easily read, and some weird characters. I wonder if this file is encoded, encrypted or sth else.  I suspect it's not encrypted because the English words could easily be read. I tried opening the file with different encodings using vim's open with encoding command, and tried utf8, utf16 and some other ones but to no avail. One part of the file looks like this (opened with Mac's `TextEdit`)

[image]

Comment: Most likely the file contains binary data and some strings. The strings can easily be read and the binary data are just binary. No matter what encoding you apply binary data remains binary - you do you can't display them as string.

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably not a text file, so no text editor can display it correctly.

You need a viewer program for its file-type. If the file-name contains a suffix,
search for the meaning of that suffix and may find what the file-type is.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, this is likely a binary file of some sort.  It is possible but unlikely that it's a text file in a legacy encoding.

Regardless, you can try to find out more about the file by running the `file` command on it, which looks at the file to see what kind of file it is.  It will look for several different common text encodings, as well as a variety of common and uncommon binary file types.

If you want to try some uncommon text encodings, you could use the `iconv -t UTF-8` command with various `-f` flags to try to see if the encoding makes sense.  `iconv -l` will list various encodings that are available, and you may wish to consult the IANA character set registry to look for character sets that are Turkish or support Turkish.

If you think it's binary, you may be able to learn more about it by running the file through the `strings` command, which looks for printable ASCII strings.